# How do I define an autocommand to work on all files excepted a certain filetype?

Tags: autocmd, filetype

For example, I have the following `autocommand` definition:

```
augroup cursorline
    autocmd!
    autocmd WinLeave,BufLeave * set nocursorline
    autocmd WinEnter,BufEnter * set cursorline
augroup end
```

I want to define something that excludes `*.tex` files:

```
autocmd WinEnter,BufEnter * "except *.tex" set cursorline
```

What is the syntax for that? I'm not sure what keywords to search the help docs.

Answer (score 8):

In the same spirit as @Sundar answer but with a little more flexible syntax you can do:

```
let ftToIgnore = ['latex', 'plaintex']
autocmd BufWritePre * if index(ftToIgnore, &ft) < 0 | set your options
```

I tend to prefer this syntax because:

- You can easily add new filtetypes if you want.
- The condition length stay the same no matter how many filetypes you're checking.

Comment: Neat ! Where did you find that you could run a condition/function inside the autocommand ?

Comment: Well its the same principe as the @sundar answer excepted the condition isn't on the value of a variable but on the return value of a function.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
autocmd WinEnter,BufEnter * if &filetype != "latex" && &filetype != "plaintex" | set cursorline | endif
```

better formatted as

```
autocmd WinEnter,BufEnter * if &filetype != "latex" && &filetype != "plaintex" 
                            \ | set cursorline 
                            \ | endif
```

This depends upon the `filetype` as detected or set by Vim, and so doesn't have any case-sensitivity issues. (You might want to check what your tex files are being detected as, by running `set filetype?` in Vim's commandline).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find anything that seems to support what you want, but you can do quite the same with a little bit of scripting :

```
function! s:ToggleCursorLine(open) abort
  let l:extension = expand('%:e')
  if l:extension !=? 'tex'
    if a:open
      set cursorline
    else
      set nocursorline
    endif
  endif
endfunction

augroup cursorline
  autocmd!
  autocmd WinLeave,BufLeave * call s:ToggleCursorLine(1)
  autocmd WinEnter,BufEnter * call s:ToggleCursorLine(0)
augroup end
```

Reference : [`:h expand()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expand())

Comment: You might want to use `!=#` instead of `!=` on UNIX, and `!=?` on Windows.  Otherwise the result depends on the value of `ignorecase`.

Comment: Could you point me to an explaination of the difference between `!=#` and `!=?` ? Because on `:h expr4` it doesn't mention Windows/Unix.

Comment: UNIX filenames are (usually) case-sensitive, Windows ones are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This works for `Syntax` autocommands, where the pattern (`<match>`) is just the filetype.  It excludes any `rst` files:

```
au Syntax *\(^rst\)\@<! …
```